# Adding a new root level property to JSON object using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a large JSON file (about 7K lines) with deeply nested items which has a missing required property `collection` that I need to add.
Current JSON object:

```
{
  "item": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "name": "Customer",
          "item": [
              {
                 "id": "456",
                 "name": "Retrieve a customer"
....
```

Using a bash script, I need to add a top level property `"collection"`  like this, which still contains the same nested items within it. This is my desired result:

```
{
  "collection": {
    "item": [
         {
           "id": "123",
           "name": "Customer",
           "item": [
               {
                "id": "456",
                "name": "Retrieve a customer",
....
```

At the end of the JSON object I also need the matching closing `}` brace at the end of the file for my newly added `collection:` key. Is there a way to do this with JQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
jq '{"collection": .}' <in.json >out.json
```

And if your JSON is the output of another jq command, just add the collection at the end, like:

```bash
# For example: delete an element and then wrap 
# entries around a "records" attribute (assuming
# the date is already a JSON list):
jq '[.[] | del(.undesiredAttribute)] | {"records": .}'
```

Then the output is:

```
{"records":[{"name":"Foo"},{"name":"Bar"}]}
```

Comment: I guess you made it a Community Wiki cause you couldn't figure out what else to say, but is there really anything else to say?

Comment: More because I have trouble believing this isn't a duplicate, but don't want the work of running down the preexisting instance yet. Answering CW splits the difference -- I'm not earning reputation from answering a question I think is probably a duplicate, which makes the decision to answer rather than close look less self-serving (though "being too lazy" arguably _is_ self-serving even so).